# android : how to play multiple audio files synchronous through media player

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-sdcard

I want to play multiple audio files simultaneously in sync. I , file on the SD-Card, or a file in a specific folder). I want to be able to put a delay on the files and adjust the play rate.

I have looked `MediaPlayer`, `MediaPlayer` seems like the right path, but they are not synchronous multiple audio into single audio.

Comment: 3x _I want to..._ What have you tried?

Comment: multiple audio play like single audio(synchronize audio).